# Failure to upgrade Ubuntu due to package removal failure of 'systemd-shim'

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

Every time a 'partial upgrade' or 'normal upgrade' of the Ubuntu OS, it is failing every time because of the failure of the `systemd-shim` package.

Even after I manually execute the following command (per the instructions post-failure) and retry the upgrade process:

```
apt-get install -f
apt autoremove systemd-shim
```

I have screen-shots but image files are 2MB+.

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Please don't post screenshot of command and their output. Always post as text formatted as code.

Comment: Just edit your question and copy and paste the output. On a blank line above the output put three backtics at the beginning of the line ``` On a blank line after the output do the same (three backtics at the beginning of the line ```). This "codefencing" will format the output as code for your question. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can copy, paste, highlight the code, and then press CTRL+K and it will format automatically.

Comment: My current OS version:

Linux 4.15.0-169-generic #177-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 10:50:38 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

Comment: Remove the package with dpkg.

Comment: I have attempted to remove he package via the dpkg program to no avail (as I just attempted generated the same results):

dpkg -r systemd-shim
(Reading database ... 262747 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services

Comment: /org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
  different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim

Comment: Maybe you can find some help in this German thread: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/problem-mit-systemd-shim/

Comment: Put the info in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no package called `systemd-shim` in Bionic (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/systemd-shim), so, you are having an obsolete and unsupported package in your system. Better purge the package using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all systemd-shim
```

Then run `autopurge` to remove the dependencies:

```
sudo apt autopurge
```

Then reinstall `systemd`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall systemd
```

Answer (score -1):

for non german, try to translate.

Package systemd-shim is since bionic no longer available.
with

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak
```

the file which is in the old(xenial)package systemd-shim and in the bionic systemd package is renamed.

Now

```
sudo dpkg -P systemd-shim
```

removed the xenial package.

For security

```
sudo apt install --reinstall systemd
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation and it addressed the root cause of the issue.

Best regards,

Comment: okay if your problem is solved;  do not forget to accept one of the answer.